# Problem with "intramfs" when loading Kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, data-recovery

I am a complete newbie with Linux in general, but i've worked with Kubuntu for two years now. Last year, my Toshiba Satellite went off because of low battery, so it shut down completely. When I tried to open my kubuntu partition from the grub, it only showed the logo and then the following appeared

"Busy Box v1.22.1", and well, I think this is pretty common, so you know the rest of the message. The problem is that that's the only thing that appears, along with the help option. Whenever I write 'exit', the whole thing crashes and it doesn't show any error messages.

Right now I booted an USB with the same Kubuntu version (14.04.04 Lts), because when I looked for help, it mentioned that if booted again from an external device, I could fix the problem.

Honestly, I only want to recover my files so I can keep on working, I was planning on using that laptop for other distribution since I got a new one and I've already installed Kubuntu 20.04.

I tried to upload an image of the screen, but I can't, so, repeating what I said previously, it doesn't show any error message, it only says the Busy Box title, and the command options, doesn't even say if there's something wrong with the partition.

Thank you so much for your help, sorry if didn't explain myself well.

Comment: "I could fix the problem". Did you fix your problem or not? Anyway as 14.04 is EOL, I suggest you remove the disk from your "old" computer and attach it (using a USB converter for example) to your "new" computer. That way you may rescue your files from the old disk. An alternative will be to boot from a newer "Live" CD/USB and copy your files to an external resource.

Comment: Upload your picture & provide a link in your post so we can look at it. 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic on this site; Kubuntu 20.04 LTS is supported & on-topic. Your initial problem was probably an unclean file-system, which can usually be fixed easily by booting *live* media (such as Kubuntu install media) and running a `fsck` (file system check) on your partitions. If errors are detected & fixed, it'll usually boot next time normally. In your case I'd still perform the `fsck` then you should be able to read the files to get them off.  GUI tools such as KDE Partition Manager can `fsck` too